# converting 6-byte emoji to 4-byte emoji and being able to read it

Tags: emoji

I write an instant messaging app on a cloud, and I have a supplemented keyboard I can't change. To my understanding, the keyboard is to blame for my problem - when I try to send a message containing an emoji, the emoji is represented as a 6-byte word, while the cloud owner has some security mechanism that only permits 4-byte word to reach the cloud. This cant be changed (I asked).

Since the security and the keyboard are given, I have to find a way to make the emoji be represented as 4-byte before sending it, or to somehow make it pass the security, but I don't have knowledge in that area. I understand there is a 4-byte standard representation to emojis, so i guess whats missing is how I convert them on my phone after typing and just before sending, and how I make the cloud convert them back (or understand that new 4-byte language).

Comment: please add the language/framework and the cloud solution. We need some more context before we can answer this.

Comment: there's no 6-byte emoji. Unicode is a 21-bit standard and all can be represented in 4 UTF-8 code units

Comment: the language i use is java, im not sure about te cloud. but im nore interested in an algorithemic idea i can then work out and match to the situation.
about the unicode - i admit i havnt seen it myself, but the owner claims he sniffed the network and he saw the emojis sent as 6-byte words. i also saw on the internet that many emojis used to have 3 byte representation, so maybe im just not using the right phrase, see an example here: http://blog.manbolo.com/2012/10/29/supporting-new-emojis-on-ios-6

Comment: Java uses UTF-16 which have maximum 4 bytes for a character. Serializing using any encoding will never exceed 4 bytes for those unless you send literal words for emoji like skype

Answer (score 0):

As I searched the intenet, I came up with:

1. I was NOT using utf-8 as I thought. the environment I was using implemented the cesu-8 encoding, which lead to 6-byte and even 8-byte words (mostly out of the BMP, like the emojis I was specifically asking about. this, I think (after my reasearch), is the only case that my problem may happen.
2. As for the conversion, I would suggest https://stackoverflow.com/a/20090519/8255555
   as it seems promising (tho I'm still reviewing it myself, I thought it may be good to mention now because it may take time for me to test it properly with my limited knowledge). There are a few more questions, some of them answered, about this topic.